# Conditionally replace data in a pandas multi-indexed dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, python-3.4

In a pandas multi-indexed dataframe, how do I set values in a column that rely on a certain condition contained in a different column?

So, I've have a dataframe that essentially looks like this:

```
           COL1      COL2      COL3      COL4
foo 1 -1.322275  1.107506  1.253344 -0.331782
    2 -0.378448 -1.174557 -0.772984  1.476661
    3  0.046396  0.904299  0.768654 -0.168910
    4  1.396580  1.250713  0.193130 -0.454971
bar 1 -1.453794 -0.393206 -0.922908  0.762605
    2  1.375954 -1.304682  0.329339  0.606340
    3 -2.911151  0.011083  0.771964  1.620039
    4  0.040204  0.887082 -0.893575  1.129227
```

You can create with this code:

```
arrays = [np.array(['foo','foo','foo','foo','bar','bar','bar','bar']),
          np.array([1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4])]
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(8,4), index=arrays)
df.columns = ['COL1','COL2','COL3','COL4']
```

I want to evaluate 'COL1', subframe 'foo' for values greater than 0 and replace (in-place not copy) 'COL4' values for the corresponding rows with a new value, COL1/1. Then I would like to do the same thing again for subframe 'bar', however evaluate 'COL2' values instead.

My actual dataframe is huge, so I've been trying to find a better solution than itterating over rows. I've been able to conditionally replace with a regular dataframe but, something isn't clicking when I try more advanced multi-indexing and setting. I'm probably making things more complicated, but I'm about 45 minutes away from charging a wall.

Comment: I don't get what you meand by 'COL1/1'. What value do you with for COL4 to have at index [foo][3]? And when evaluating COL2, do you wish to replace COL4 values again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't quite get what you mean to substitute in your 'target' column, so I made something a little generic. You can replace bits as needed.

Here are the definitions:

```
def repfunc(row,evalcol,replacecol):
    if row[evalcol] > 0:
        row[replacecol] = 999 #replace value goes here!
    return row

def repframe(df,repindex,evalcol,replacecol):
    df.sort_index(inplace=True)
    df.loc[repindex][replacecol] = df.loc[repindex].apply(lambda x: repfunc(x,evalcol,replacecol), axis=1).loc[:,replacecol]
```

And here's how you call it:

```
repframe(df,'foo','COL1','COL4')
```

You can replace the parameters to repeat the operation in another slice/columns of the dataframe, as needed. The above operation changes a dataframe like this:

```
           COL1      COL2      COL3      COL4
foo 1  1.436672  0.213772 -0.705179 -1.297816
    2 -0.995535 -0.067389  0.290504 -0.794496
    3  1.375566  0.271896 -0.577298 -1.450002
    4 -0.603792 -0.450790 -1.484757  1.401513
bar 1  0.975558 -0.645254 -0.760839 -0.629055
    2 -1.972025 -0.108141  1.317623  0.126768
    3  1.947666  1.270041 -0.034555 -1.540862
    4 -3.124269  0.176528  1.815705  0.299059
```

Into this:

```
           COL1      COL2      COL3        COL4
bar 1  0.975558 -0.645254 -0.760839   -0.629055
    2 -1.972025 -0.108141  1.317623    0.126768
    3  1.947666  1.270041 -0.034555   -1.540862
    4 -3.124269  0.176528  1.815705    0.299059
foo 1  1.436672  0.213772 -0.705179  999.000000
    2 -0.995535 -0.067389  0.290504   -0.794496
    3  1.375566  0.271896 -0.577298  999.000000
    4 -0.603792 -0.450790 -1.484757    1.401513
```

I think you had problems with resetting a column of a dataframe with multiindex  because the multiindex needs to be sorted for operations to return views (and not copies) of the dataframe. This is [necessary if you want to perform this kind of replacement in multiindexed dataframes](http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/advanced.html#the-need-for-sortedness-with-multiindex), as far as I know. Note that `repframe` calls `sort_index` with `inplace=True`.

My version always replaces the positive values with 999. It does 'apply' over the rows, but I can't quite get how you could do this without that.

Comment: You Rock! You definately pointed me down the right path. Your version works, however it still throws that stupid view vs. copy error. (I'm using pandas0.15.2) Is the error flagged because the lambda isdecoupling the .loc in repframe?

Comment: I mean to do something like this `row[replacecol] = (row[evalcol]) / 5` with `repfunc()`, but am still having issues.

Comment: Thanks. Good to know it worked. I don't know about that message - I'm using the exact same pandas version. Is it just a warning message?

Comment: It is a Setting With Copy Warning. Just a warning for your implementation, but if I try to do something different with `row[replacecol] =` (above comment) it errors out.